# Eclipse Formatting newline before loops/if-else

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

I know that you can change the formatting of Eclipse in 
 Window>Preferences>Java>Code Style>Formatter 
But I don't know where to make it put a newline between variables and loops/if-else.

I need this:

```java
isRunning = true;
final double frameTime = 1.0 / FRAME_CAP;
long lastTime = Time.getTime();
double unproccessedTime = 0;
while(isRunning)
{
    long startTime = Time.getTime();
    long passedTime = startTime - lastTime;
    lastTime = startTime;
    unproccessedTime += passedTime / (double)Time.SECOND;
    while(unproccessedTime > frameTime)
    {
        unproccessedTime -= frameTime;
        if(Window.isCloseRequested())
        {
            stop();
        }
    }
    render();
}
```

To become more like this:

```java
isRunning = true;
final double frameTime = 1.0 / FRAME_CAP;
long lastTime = Time.getTime();
double unproccessedTime = 0;

while(isRunning)
{
    long startTime = Time.getTime();
    long passedTime = startTime - lastTime;
    lastTime = startTime;
    unproccessedTime += passedTime / (double)Time.SECOND;

    while(unproccessedTime > frameTime)
    {
        unproccessedTime -= frameTime;

        if(Window.isCloseRequested())
        {
            stop();
        }
    }
    render();
}
```

Can anyone tell me which format setting could perform this?

Comment: Don't think this is possible, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I have looked for a solution in various places, so if there is nobody here that knows the answer, then I believe it is indeed not possible to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to working with clean code too,and was wondering the same thing before, But I use Regex with Find and Replace:

```
Find: ^.+if

Replace with: \R$0

Find: ^\s*\n

Replace with: (empty)
```

This was answer I found before that does works as well

[How to add a new line BEFORE a line that matches a given pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826794/how-to-add-a-new-line-before-a-line-that-matches-a-given-pattern)