# How to add a new line BEFORE a line that matches a given pattern?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file with entries like below

```
LondonTableABC
ROW1
Cell1
Row2
ParisTableBCD
ROW1
ROW2
NewYorkTableEFG
ROW1
ROW2
```

I want to insert a line break before the matching pattern "Table" in the file. Find and replace has been my friend for a task like this to insert a new line AFTER the matching pattern but I can't figure out how to insert it BEFORE the matching pattern.

The result I expect after the replacement is

```
LondonTableABC
ROW1
Cell1
Row2

ParisTableBCD
ROW1
ROW2

NewYorkTableEFG
ROW1
ROW2
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure to well understand your needs, but I guess you want:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+Table`
- Replace with: `\n$0`
- *check Match case* ( if wanted )
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : begining of line
.+      : 1 or more any character
Table   : literally Table
```

**Replacement:**

```
\n      : line break (you could use \r\n if requested)
$0      : whole match (ie. Table)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
LondonTableABC
ROW1
Cell1
Row2

ParisTableBCD
ROW1
ROW2

NewYorkTableEFG
ROW1
ROW2
```

Comment: Exactly what I want. Thank you very much!

Comment: I was missing the $0 from my attempts and ending up corrupting the file.

Comment: @Toto thanks it helped me with this (3rd comment) https://stackoverflow.com/q/76935145/10789707

Answer (score 2):

Open Find Replace (CTRL+H)

Select "Extended" in search mode

Find what: `Pattern`

Replace With: `\nPattern`

Replace All

Comment: There is a small problem with this Find:[\S]*Pattern and Replace with: \n[\S]*Pattern is replacing the text literally. So Find works fine but replace doesn't.